# I rotated some text in bootstrap, and now it is stuck an inch from the left onscreen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I have rotated a like of text 90 degrees in a bootstrap column, and now I can't get it to center to the column or move any further left. I tried using padding, align, and center-block, but nothing will make it move further left. It's like it hit a wall on the left side for some reason.

Here's the html:

```css
#whatis {
  padding-top: 120px;
}
#vertical {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  font-family: 'Oranienbaum', serif;
  min-width: 315px;
  color: #231B65;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 4px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="pg03" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="whatis" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <h3 id="vertical" class="center-block"> What is Omni X?</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="infobox" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="info" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="img" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <a href="birdgirl.jpg">
                <img src="birdgirl.jpg" class="center-block">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div id="info" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="img" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <a href="birdgirl.jpg">
                <img src="birdgirl.jpg" class="center-block">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any solutions or help would be very appreciated!

Comment: yes, probably because of `transform-origin`

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments under the question, this is a `transform-origin` problem which takes a little bit of maths to figure out.

To get the correct rotation you need to add a `transform-origin` of `50% 150%` and it will give you your desired output.

Below is a working demo and you can see the elements fit within the borders and sizes set.

If you need the text to be a little bit higher, then just reduce it down in `10% 30%` increments.

```css
#whatis {
  padding-top: 120px;
}
#vertical {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 150%;
  font-family: 'Oranienbaum', serif;
  min-width: 315px;
  color: #231B65;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 4px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="pg03" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="whatis" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <h3 id="vertical" class="center-block"> What is Omni X?</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="infobox" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="info" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="img" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <a href="birdgirl.jpg">
                <img src="birdgirl.jpg" class="center-block">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div id="info" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="img" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <a href="birdgirl.jpg">
                <img src="birdgirl.jpg" class="center-block">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```